# Transfer application from one cloud to the another

Tags: azure, cloud

Is there a tool which can transfer an Application/Code base from the Google Cloud to Azure Cloud?

Or is there a tool which can help with the process?

I tried Google but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you will not be able to find any tool helping out with code migration from Google Cloud over to Azure Cloud (or vice versa).

[Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine) as well as [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) are Platform as a Service ([PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaaS)). Windows Azure also provides Infrastructure as a service ([IaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service#Infrastructure_as_a_service_.28IaaS.29)). Both platforms supports many different programming languages e.g. Java, PHP, Python etc. In many cases you can even use the same libraries (performing specific tasks) in both platforms. But that is pretty much is as far as similarities are concerned.

Each platform uses different architecture and different services;  you need to use different SDKs. Also having in mind the fact that both platforms are dynamically evolving, it is practically not possible to a tool which allows you to transfer code base from one platform to another.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Are there maybe other ways to simplify/help with the process except for a tool?

Comment: That all depends on case by case basis as each application is different. Couple of tips: in most cases migration of loosely coupled system is much easier than tightly coupled system; proper software architecture i.e. _good_ abstraction of components will also help a lot. But as I said, all depends on application - its requirements, constraints etc. and it is really hard to come up with a decent advice which would be applicable to most of the applications.